# LSTM layer followed by BatchNorm Layer error in dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a model with the following architecture :

```
self.lstm1 = nn.LSTM(in_channels, hidden_channels, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout_prob)
self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_channels)

self.lstm2 = nn.LSTM(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout_prob)
self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_channels)

self.lstm3 = nn.LSTM(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout_prob)
self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_channels)

self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_channels, out_channels)
```

```
in_channels = 105
hidden_channels = 128
batch_size = 32
Dimension of the data is : (32,770,105)
Dimension of the output from lstm1 : (32,770,128)
```

When I am trying to train the network when I reach batchnorm1 layer I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 770 elements not 128
```

Can you let me know where the mistake is ?

I tried to use permeute to change the output dimesnion from  (32,770,128) to (32,128,770) but still I was getting  different error.

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization is performed before lstm layer (regardless of the order you add them to your network), so You should set:

```
in_features = 770
self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(in_features)
self.lstm1 = nn.LSTM(in_channels, hidden_channels, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout_prob)


self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_channels)
self.lstm2 = nn.LSTM(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout_prob)

self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_channels)
self.lstm3 = nn.LSTM(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout_prob)

self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_channels, out_channels)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I have changed my forward function to be :

`out = self.batchnorm1(x)

 out, _ = self.lstm1(out)

out = self.batchnorm2(out)

out, _ = self.lstm2(out)
`
But I am still getting the same error on batchnorm2